# Styles from .css file not applying but do so from local .jsp tag <style>

Tags: html, css, jsp, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html and styles apply fine when they are defined within the page but when I move the style to a .css it doesn't apply (using bootstrap with jsp so not sure if that applies or not).

NOTE: I have other styles in that .css that are styling html properly on the .jsp page.  Just not this particular wontStyle class.

index.jsp

```
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="span2">
         <div class="well">
           <div class="wontStyle">  <!-- This won't style in .css but will style inside page -->
```

If I apply the following in the page  tag it applies the margin and padding (it works).

```
   <style>
     .wontStyle{
        margin-top: -9px !important; 
        padding-bottom: 18px !important;
    } 
  </style>
```

However, if I move the style to mystyle.css it won't apply the styles anymore (doesn't work)?

mystyle.css

```
 .wontStyle{
    margin-top: -9px !important; 
    padding-bottom: 18px !important;
}
```

included in my index.jsp

```
<link href="content/css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

How can I get it to apply styles from my .css file?

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

The issue was with the following bootstrap modal collapse style missing a } was breaking wontstyle when placed below the collapse.

```
 .collapse  {
         .transition(height .15s ease);
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
         height: 0;
         &.in {
          height: auto; 
 }
```

I didn't see any errors in chrome on console for .css.  How can I catch something like this in the future (css pages failing to load or breaking mid-point/etc,)?

Comment: Did you try defining the style as #wrapper .wontStyle instead of just .wontStyle.

Comment: It's really odd.  Even if I pull the <div> out of that deep nesting and put it right below the <body> tag it still isn't styling.  Even adding another <div class="whatever"></div> and adding the css in the file isn't styling.  No clue what is going on here. Of course even if I move the new style for "whatever" into the .jsp directly it of course styles fine. .whatever {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #000;
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

Comment: Ok, if I add the style within the .css file it finally styles.  I had the style ast the bottom of the .css file so something above it is failing to load styles below.  So just need to find where it's breaking.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing } in the following style within the .css file which was above "wontstyle".  Thus preventing my style to load from the css file itself.

```
 .collapse  {
         .transition(height .15s ease);
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
         height: 0;
         &.in {
          height: auto; // }  <-- Needs a  bracket here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using JSP, you have to reference your CSS file in the context of your application. For example, you can use `<c:url>` from the [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) to define the path to whatever CSS/JS/image file you need. Assuming that your CSS file is located a few folders further from your current location in /content/css you can do the following after importing `<c:url>` from Oracle:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/content/css/mystle.css' />" />
```

Comment: That's not the problem. because it loads the file fine.  It's just not styling it from the css file.  I have other styles are being styled from the same .css just not that particular style that I call out in the description.  I'll edit my ask to be more clear.